# How to use ImageMagick to substract a image from another?

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, alpha

I have this two images :

[image: First]
<sub>(source: [free.fr](http://hubscher.remy.free.fr/tally/images/2011/01/24/first591.jpg))</sub>

[image: Second]
<sub>(source: [free.fr](http://hubscher.remy.free.fr/tally/images/2011/01/24/second593.jpg))</sub>

How can I use imagemagick to remove the background (second picture) from the first one ?

Cheers,

Rémy

Here I made you a final but simple example :

[Transparent Overlay http://noosphere.ionyse.com/transparent_example/transparent_difference.png](http://noosphere.ionyse.com/transparent_example/transparent_difference.png)
[Background http://noosphere.ionyse.com/transparent_example/background.png](http://noosphere.ionyse.com/transparent_example/background.png)

[Example 1 http://noosphere.ionyse.com/transparent_example/background-example.png](http://noosphere.ionyse.com/transparent_example/background-example.png)
[Example 2 http://noosphere.ionyse.com/transparent_example/background-example2.png](http://noosphere.ionyse.com/transparent_example/background-example2.png)

Here you see that anywhere I put the transparent overlay on the background I get the perfect match using the opacity of the overlay PNG.

I would like to be able to calculate this overlay image. Do you think it is possible using ImageMagick ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is explained over here [How to save the DIFFERENCES between two images ?](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=15584&start=0).

Another useful link: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/compare/#difference

Comment: Actualy I would like the difference to be a maximum of transparency so I can add the mask over any part of the background and that the result is ok. It is for the background menu of this image : http://lagrange-avins.fr/accueil/

Comment: The perfect match looking closer to : http://lagrange-avins.fr/medias/img/fond-repeat-bottom.png

Comment: I see. This assumes that the "overlay"-image has absolutely no semi-transparent parts. Is this true for your case?

Comment: In the current image there is some semi-transparent parts. But my aim is to calculate them precisely.

Comment: But how would you be able to tell if, say, a "grey" part is semi-transparent white, on top of black, or non-transparent grey?

Comment: It why I need to calculate pixel by pixel the transparent différence to get the exact wanted color. If I substract the background, I will get the transparent difference to get the final result.

Comment: This answer doesn't contain direct information and the URLs are vulnerable to linkrot.